# i want onclick image popup this image and display it with another images same id in database

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I used this code source and only the first image worked. i need to display image2 and image3 and image4 from datatabse only images same id first image.

`i display image in php page like this`

```
<div  >
         <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){ ?>
            <img id="myImg" style="cursor: pointer;" src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 portfolio-item hover-bg img-responsive myImages " >
             <?php }; ?>


              </div>
```

`my modal`

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close cursor">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" style="width:100%" id="img01">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image2']; ?>" style="width:100%"  >
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image3']; ?>" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image4']; ?>" style="width:100%" >
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" id="img01">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image2']; ?>" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" >
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image3']; ?>" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="uploaded_img/<?php echo $row['image4']; ?>" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 // create references to the modal...
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var navhide = document.getElementById('menu');
// to all images -- note I'm using a class!
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImages');
// the image in the modal
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
// and the caption in the modal
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

// Go through all of the images with our custom class
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  // and attach our click listener for this image.
  img.onclick = function(evt) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    navhide.style.display = "none";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  navhide.style.display = "block";
}

</script>
```

`modal css`

```
 <style type="text/css">
  /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
      height: auto;
      width: 80%;
    }
}
</style>
```

I used this code source above and only the first image worked

Comment: Doesn't appear to be your issue but `myImg` should really be a class, not an id.